# Deactivate Certificates in Salesforce

Tags: certificates, custom-domain, key

There is a certificate created in my org and it is expired.
I want to deactivate it. Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's being used by your Identity Provider function or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the delete option for this certificate, you have to replace it with an existing one on the Identity Provider.

Open the expired certificate, hover on the delete button (if the button is greyed out) then you will find the information where that certificate is used.

Usually deletion of an expired certificate fails when it is being used in any of the below three places

1. Single Sign-On
2. Connected Apps
3. Identity Provider

From Setup --> Go to Identity provider --> Replace it with existing certificates --> Save.

Go to Setup --> Certificate and Key Management --> You will see the delete option now .

You can review details [steps](https://www.craftsmantech.com/2020/08/26/expiring-salesforce-certificate-now-what/) and remove certificates [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000329338&type=1), along with how to [delete Unused Certificate](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320227&type=1).

Comment: Thank you Vinay